# Multiple negative lookbehind assertions in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to programming, sorry if this seems trivial: I have a text that I'm trying to split into individual sentences using regular expressions. With the `.split` method I search for a dot followed by a capital letter like

```
"\. A-Z"
```

However I need to refine this rule in the following way: The `.` (dot) may not be preceeded by either `Abs` or `S`. And if it is followed by a capital letter (`A-Z`), it should still not match if it is a month name, like `January | February | March`.

I tried implementing the first half, but even this did not work. My code was:

```
"( (?<!Abs)\. A-Z) | (?<!S)\. A-Z) ) "
```

Comment: I suggest replacing the space with `\s+` (or `\s` if it really needs to be exactly one space). And matching an uppercase letter would be `[A-Z]` (you forgot the brackets).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, I think you may want to replace the space with `\s+`, or `\s` if it really is exactly one space (you often find double spaces in English text).

Second, to match an uppercase letter you have to use `[A-Z]`, but `A-Z` will not work (but remember there may be other uppercase letters than `A-Z` ...).

Additionally, I think I know why this does not work. The regular expression engine will try to match `\. [A-Z]` if it is not preceeded by `Abs` or `S`. The thing is that, if it is preceeded by an `S`, it is *not* preceeded by `Abs`, so the first pattern matches. If it is preceeded by `Abs`, it is *not* preceeded by `S`, so the second pattern version matches. In either way one of those patterns will match since `Abs` and `S` are mutually exclusive.

The pattern for the first part of your question could be

```
(?<!Abs)(?<!S)(\. [A-Z])
```

or

```
(?<!Abs)(?<!S)(\.\s+[A-Z])
```

(with my suggestion)

That is because you have to avoid `|`, without it the expression now says *not preceeded by Abs* and *not preceeded by S*. If both are true the pattern matcher will continue to scan the string and find your match.

To exclude the month names I came up with this regular expression:

```
(?<!Abs)(?<!S)(\.\s+)(?!January|February|March)[A-Z]
```

The same arguments hold for the negative look ahead patterns.

Comment: I'm new to multiple look-behinds. It looks like (?<!Abs)(?<!S) does the same as (?<!Abs|S). Is there any advantage to either (beyond personal preference on brevity/readability)?

Comment: @jhiro009  Yes, when you lump them together with the OR (pipe) operator, regex requires them to be a fixed-width pattern, so Abs and S are incompatible. You'd *have* to use the former case, in this situation.

Answer (score 9):

I'm adding a short answer to the question in the title, since this is at the top of Google's search results:

The way to have multiple differently-lengthed negative lookbehinds is to chain them together like this:

`"(?<!1)(?<!12)(?<!123)example"`

This would match `example` `2example` and `3example` but not `1example` `12example` or `123example`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [nltk punkt tokenizer](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tokenize.html). It's <s>probably</s> more robust than using regex.

```
>>> import nltk.data
>>> text = """
... Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
... do not mark sentence boundaries.  And sometimes sentences
... can start with non-capitalized words.  i is a good variable
... name.
... """
>>> sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> print '\n-----\n'.join(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip()))
Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
do not mark sentence boundaries.
-----
And sometimes sentences
can start with non-capitalized words.
-----
i is a good variable
name.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nltk or similar tools as suggested by @root.

To answer your regex question:

```
import re
import sys

print re.split(r"(?<!Abs)(?<!S)\.\s+(?!January|February|March)(?=[A-Z])",
               sys.stdin.read())
```

#### Input

```
First. Second. January. Third. Abs. Forth. S. Fifth.
S. Sixth. ABs. Eighth
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/tBoVj)

```
['First', 'Second. January', 'Third', 'Abs. Forth', 'S. Fifth',
 'S. Sixth', 'ABs', 'Eighth']
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Set [].

'(?<![1,2,3]example)'

This would not match 1example, 2example, 3example.